# Managing access of millions of devices to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

We have a requirement of of millions of devices to access resources in AWS S3. Each of device has its own certificate, issued by global private CA, to authenticate itself to AWS. For each device, there's going to be seperate prefix (like $global_bucket/$device_type/$device_id/) to which it would have access.

My question is whether you think such a setup can be supported out of the box (i.e. without any custom component) in AWS. Whether its possible to configure IAM with ACM to authenticate the device (using device certificate in request) and authorize it (using role and condition based policy) in IAM? Given the constraints in AWS IAM around maximum number of users in one account.